# Absolute Footer is floating around in mobile browser

Tags: css, mobile, footer, css-position

Help! Sorry if this question is answered somewhere, I tried to find it, I really did. Read plenty of stuff about fixed positioning in mobile browsers, but that isn't what I want.

All I want, is a button (read: footer div) to sit at the very bottom of the page (NOT viewport) regardless of whether the page is long enough to warrant scrolling or not. I can totally understand why mobile browsers have a problem with "fixed" positioning, but I am not trying to align my button with the viewport. I want it to be positioned absolutely in the DOCUMENT. Nevertheless, the div is doing some form of half-a**ed fixed positioning. Moving with the viewport, but not even making it to the bottom of the page (it gets stuck). Why can't I define my div's position in the document? Is this impossible without Javascript? It doesn't make sense that it should.

Here's what I'm doing

```
<!doctype HTML>
<html><head>...
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
...
<body><div class='container'>

...

<div class='footer'></div>
</div></body></html>
```

CSS

```
html{
    height:100%;
}

body{
    height:100%;
}

.container{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
}

.footer{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    left:0px;
}
```

Instinct tells me this SHOULD work... obviously I'm wrong. Is it not possible to do even THIS kind of positioning in mobile browsers, or did I mess something up? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind... Think I solved it! "min-height:100%;" seems to do the trick. Thanks though.